# Всегда ли работают школьные методики (выбор формы написания НЕ)?

Tags: методика

"Есть методический прием, практически универсальный для существительных, прилагательных и наречий на -О(Е)- это замена синонимом. Можно - пиши слитно, нет - раздельно".

1) Действительно, всё сходится, метод работает (слитное написание при замене синонимом):

Я  негромко (тихо) свистнул, подзывая собаку. 
Изучение незнакомого (чужого) края всегда начинается с карты.
Не бывать бы счастью, да несчастье (горе) помогло.

2) А здесь почему раздельно?

Не простое это дело – топором махать умело. Жизнью молодою не долго наслаждаться ей. Уездный лекарь был не глупый.  Приветствую тебя, Кавказ седой! Твоим горам я путник не чужой. Роль поэта – не легкая и не веселая. Не простое это дело – топором махать умело.

3) А это парные варианты! Авторские, наверное. Или нет?

Пушкин ненадолго покинул Одессу. Увы, не надолго нам счастье дано.

Нескоро ели предки наши, нескоро двигались кругом ковши, серебряные чаши.
Плачь, мое бедное отечество! Не скоро родишь ты такого сына!

Справится ли школьник с таким заданием, как выбор написания НЕ в этих самых обычных предложениях художественной речи, если он обычно решает только однозначные учебные примеры? Как вы думаете? А если не справится, то кто виноват и что делать?

Comment: Это не однозначные примеры. И не авторские. Разный смысл - разное написание. А смысл фразы, конечно, может понять только автор фразы. Или очень вдумчивый и внимательный читатель в контексте, а не в отдельно вырванной фразе. Слово ненадолго из другой оперы. Замена синонимов относится к наречиям на -О, образованным от прилагательных.

Comment: Давайте конкретно. Две формы написания: "ненадолго" (на короткое время) и "не надолго" (на не очень продолжительное время) имеют разную семантику. НО в предложении "Пушкин ненадолго покинул Одессу" мы эту разную семантику выразить не можем, а в предложении  "Увы, не надолго нам счастье дано" мы это можем сделать, здесь у нас авторская свобода. Почему?

Comment: >> в предложении "Пушкин ненадолго покинул Одессу" мы эту разную семантику выразить не можем, а в предложении "Увы, не надолго нам счастье дано" мы это можем сделать, здесь у нас авторская свобода. Почему?

Второе предложение в пассиве - думаю, в этом все дело. Или не все дело, но часть дела уж точно. ))

Comment: А "Жизнью молодою не долго наслаждаться ей". Или ещё пример: "Не надолго вернулось лето". Здесь-то нет пассива.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > 2) А здесь почему раздельно?

1. (Не) простое это дело... Возможны оба варианта.
2. (не) долго наслаждаться... Возможны оба варианта. Я бы выбрал слитное написание.
3. лекарь был (не) глупый. Возможны оба варианта.
4. путник не чужой. Слова "нечужой" нет. Так уж вышло, что языку оно не нужно. В словари полезно заглядывать и, опять же, книжки читать. В книжках "нечужого" не встретим.
5. Роль поэта – (не) легкая и (не) веселая. Возможны оба варианта. Я бы выбрал раздельное написание.

Школьникам редко дают такие задания на оценку! И это правильно. Но такие упражнения полезны, развивают языковое чутье, и хороший учитель иногда должен их предлагать.

> > Справится ли школьник с таким заданием, как выбор написания НЕ в этих самых обычных предложениях художественной речи, если он обычно решает только однозначные учебные примеры? Как вы думаете? А если не справится, то кто виноват и что делать?

-- Ниччего не делать! -- сказал капитан Жеглов. Не справится сегодня - справится завтра. Тем более что однозначных ответов нет.

Comment: А как определить, когда возможны оба варианта и когда только один? Например: "Пушкин ненадолго покинул Одессу". "Я невольно залюбовался Павлушей". В этих предложениях только слитное написание. А в предложении "Не надолго нам счастье дано" можно применить обе формы. Почему? Или вот полный текст предложения: "Уездный лекарь был не глупый, выражался бойко и довольно забавно". Вы по-прежнему допускаете обе формы? И различаются ли они   по смыслу?

Comment: >> А как определить, когда возможны оба варианта и когда только один?
Это на филфаке, это не в школе.
Или на факультативе.

>> Или вот полный текст предложения: "Уездный лекарь был не глупый, выражался бойко и довольно забавно". Вы по-прежнему допускаете обе формы? И различаются ли они по смыслу?
Да, допускаю обе. Предпочел бы слитное написание. Различаются: либо отрицаем глупость, либо утверждаем "неглупость" (в кавычки взял, потому что нет такого слова). Хозяин барин. Что плохого, когда хозяин барин?!

Comment: И вот еще вопрос: какой смысл имеет проверка с помощью замены синонимом? Когда она действительно работает, а когда применять ее не имеет смысла? И почему школьникам это противопоказано знать?

Comment: Вы хотите на уроках русского языка развивать у школьников математическое мышление? Простые однозначные правила, по возможности без исключений... Так на то есть уроки математики, а на уроках русского языка надо развивать языковое чутье. Помогать развивать! И тут без чтения не обойтись. Хочет школьник, интересно ему - он читает и обращает на все внимание. Нет - ничего вы с ним не сделаете, в более-менее сложных случаях он будет плавать. Чутья нет!

Comment: Почему же на филфаке? Вот в 5-6-7 классе школьники прошли правило о замене синонимом, при этом значительная часть написаний этим правилом не объясняется. Неужели за последующие 5 лет, повзрослевшие и поумневшие, они не имеют право узнать нечто большее. Почему они учатся брать интегралы, но не изучают язык, которым они пользуются постоянно? И по поводу лекаря. Если вы только что увидели человека, то вряд ли по его речи можно сделать вывод, что он неглупый (довольно умный), скорее, вы подумаете, что глупым его не назовешь.

Comment: А-а, какой смысл имеет замена синонимом? Ну, это же понятно - проверить, есть ли отрицание (помним основной принцип!). Почему иногда не работает... так, с ходу не могу ответить.
А вы можете сказать, почему слова "несильно", "несильный" есть, а "неслабо" - это сленг, а "неслабый" если и есть, все-таки употребляется чрезвычайно редко?

Comment: София, это уж такие нюансы, которые видите только вы... И не думаю, что вы здесь правы, с лекарем.
Почему не изучают-то?! При чем тут "право знать"? Кто хочет - тот знает, а все всё равно знать не могут. И потом - вы приводите примеры, подавляющее большинство из которых допускают оба варианта написания. Это не совсем корректно.

Уверяю вас, что те "интегралы", которые берут школьники, соответствуют их знаниям по русскому языку. В среднем.

Comment: Если не всегда работает, то как им пользоваться, дополнительные инструкции нужны. Принцип здесь необходимый, но не достаточный, так говорят математики? А что касается Вашего вопроса, то здесь действует градация признака: большой- не большой и не маленький - небольшой - маленький; сильный - неслабый - не сильный и не слабый - несильный - слабый. Вероятно, неслабый - лишний вариант.

Answer (score 4):

В свое время я усвоил пояснение Розенталя о слитном или раздельном написании НЕ в зависимости от утверждения или отрицания. Для того чтобы ученикам было понятнее это правило, я обычно объяснял им так: "Эта книга неинтересная (утверждаем, что она неинтересная, т.е. скучная, можно заменить синонимом - Эта книга не интересная (отрицаем, что книга интересная, но не утверждаем, что она скучная, т.е. серединка на половинку, или fifty - fifty, как говорит молодежь). Мои ученики легко усваивали такое объяснение. По-моему, любой из приведенных выше примеров вполне можно так интерпретировать. Не правда ли?

Answer (score 4):

София, Вы всё пытаетесь здесь обвинить учителей, что они не так учат. Не знаю,КТО ВЫ, где Вы видели учителя, который бы объяснял написание НЕ только возможностью замены синонимом. Это целый блок правил. У каждого учителя своя метода. У меня так: (Блок 5. НЕ со всеми частями речи)

I. раздельно

1) с глаголом, деепричастием,кратким причастием,числительным, относит. прилаг.,
со всеми неизмен. ч.речи, кроме наречий на –о,    с модальными словами, краткими прилагательными, не имеющ. полной формы (не рад, не нужен, не  способен, не прав, не расположен, не готов, не намерен, не согласен, не обязан)

2) есть или подразумевается противопоставление; отрицат.мест. или наречие; в словосоч. далеко не…,вовсе не, отнюдь не ; част.ЛИ подтверждает отрицание 
(не правда ли…)

3) с полн. причастиями, если есть завис.слово;
с прил. и прич. на –мый – зав.слово должно быть в творит.пад.; прич. об. стоит после определяемого слова (несгибаемая в локте рука, но рука, не сгибаемая в локте)

4) в отрицат. местоимениях, если есть внутри предлог

II.слитно

1)без НЕ не употребляется

2)в производном предлоге несмотря на…, невзирая на…

3)в отрицат. наречиях (негде, некогда)

4)возможна замена    СИНОНИМОМ

5)пояснительные слова обозначают степень качества (почти, ОЧЕНЬ, весьма, крайне, абсолютно, совершенно, совсем, слишком и др)

6)приставка НЕДО обознач. недостаточность  действия, качества (недосмотреть за ребёнком – не досмотреть фильм, недостаёт смелости – не достаёт до полки)

7) в отрицат. местоимениях, если нет внутри предлога(некем – не  С   кем)

Как видите, на "универсальной" замене синонимом мы не останавливаемся. Интересно, а кто Вы по профессии и где пересекаетесь с такими нерадивыми учителями, с которыми приходится спорить?

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила, за Ваш ответ, присоединяюсь, хотелось те же вопросы задать Софии.

Comment: Ларf, а на мой вопрос Вы не хотите ответить? (Он на самом верхнем поле, посмотрите, пожалуйста).

Comment: София, извините, не хочется. Потому что что-то не получается в нашем общении. Воистину, "мысль изреченная есть ложь". Я в комментарии к другому вопросу говорила о конкретном приеме к конкретным частям речи. Вы, цитируя мой комментарий, называете это школьной методикой обучения слитному-раздельному написанию НЕ, обвиняя тем самым учителей то ли в безграмотности, то ли в непрофессионализме. Так что от дискуссии увольте.

Comment: Я не прокурор, Ларf. Согласитесь, что слово "вина" несет в себе очень неприятную энергетику, и я никого и никогда не обвиняю, в моем словаре отсутствует это понятие. Мы все учимся В ЭТОЙ ЖИЗНИ, мы все лишь ученики, и методики наших наставников нам незнакомы. Наверное, мы не очень прилежны, и много раз заучиваем один и тот же жизненный урок.

Comment: Учитель - такая трудная профессия, не каждому дано быть хорошим учителем. И в неэффективных методиках виновата сама орфографическая наука, а не практикующие учителя (им теорией заниматься некогда). Поэтому, пожалуйста, не принимайте ничего на свой счет. Я как раз думаю, что Вы очень хороший учитель и Вас очень любят Ваши ученики. Привет, ребята! Вам очень повезло с вашим педагогом.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно, имеет значение противопоставления. ( помимо синонимии). . Пишутся раздельно с не наречия на -о, если имеется или подразумевается противопоставление, например: живут не богато, а бедно; обычно ехали не быстро и не медленно; не часто возникает подобная ситуация;
 Примечание 1. В некоторых случаях возможно двоякое толкование текста и, как следствие, двоякое написание; ср.: ***до ближайшей остановки автобуса отсюда недалеко (утверждается, что близко)  до ближайшей остановки автобуса отсюда не далеко (отрицается, что далеко); редактор уехал ненадолго (на короткое время)  редактор уехал не надолго (не на продолжительное время).***
О пояснительных словах при отрицании, думаю, всем известно.
 5. Слитно или раздельно пишутся с не так называемые предикативные наречия на -о (слова категории состояния) типа нетрудно видеть  не трудно видеть: ***при утверждении они пишутся слитно, при отрицании  раздельно (критерий того и другого смысла обычно устанавливается самим пишущим)***. Например:
          а***) неважно, что он о нас думает; неверно считать создавшееся положение столь трудным; невозможно выполнить такую сложную работу в короткий срок; невыгодно уезжать немедленно; неизвестно, как он будет себя вести дальше; немудрено, что она отказалась от неинтересной работы;*** ***непозволительно так относиться к старшим; непонятно.***

Трудность, на мой взгляд, именно в этом пункте. Утверждение - отрицание. Недалеко (утверждается, что близко)не далеко((отрицается, что далеко);  Разве это не то же самое? Если отрицается, что "Не далеко" ,значит, = близко. А если близко, то почему не написать " Недалеко"?

Comment: Недалеко - утверждается, что близко. Н далеко - отрцается, что далеко, но не утверждается, что близко, т.е. серединка на половинку, как я уже пояснял

Comment: >> Трудность, на мой взгляд, именно в этом пункте. Утверждение - отрицание

Никаких трудностей. Вернее, это придуманные трудности. В подавляющем большинстве случаев такая тонкая нюансировка не нужна. Хозяин барин, как нам хочется, так и пишем.

Comment: Извините, рано нажал на ввод. Не далеко - отрицается, что далеко, но не утверждается, что близко

Comment: @виктор1799, в течении часа после написания, свои комментарии можно исправлять, если нажать значок карандашика чуть ниже текста. При наведении на неё курсора появляется надпись "править запись".

Comment: Все ясно. Но поймет ли все эти правила школьник?

Comment: Существуют прилагательные с градацией признака: далекий - не далекий/не близкий - недалекий - близкий. У них  семантика зависит от формы написания, и это отнюдь не тонкая нюансировка, ее важно выразить. Но сделать это можно не всегда, например: в недалеком будущем - только слитное написание, и никаких "хозяев", здесь строгая орфография. С другой стороны, если такой градации нет, то лучше использовать слитное написание, например: "Непонятно, что он хотел сказать".

Comment: Вообще говоря, именно отрицательные конструкции требуют обоснования, вот например: Не важно, что он о нас думает, важно, что он выполняет наши указания (скрытое противопоставление).Поэтому важно спросить себя или автора: что мы хотим сказать, используя отрицание там, где возможно утверждение?

Comment: >> Все ясно. Но поймет ли все эти правила школьник?

И что вы все так беспокоитесь о школьнике... Нормальный школьник понимает. И пишет в целом грамотно, и часто даже может объяснить. Вы не путаете среднюю школу с филфаком, нет?

Answer (score 0):

Людмила, вы пишете, что "не" раздельно 
1) с...  краткими прилагательными, не имеющ. полной формы (не рад, не нужен, не способен, не прав, не расположен, не готов, не намерен, не согласен, не обязан).

Но по-моему, среди приведенных примеров только слово "рад" не имеет полной формы. Остальные же имеют полную форму, но смысл ее отличается от смысла соответствующего слова в краткой форме: нужен - нужный, способен - способный и т. д.

должен - ‘обязан сделать что-л.’: должен выполнить работу в срок
должный - ‘такой, как нужно; подобающий’: оказать должное внимание; ответить должным образом.

Только в краткой форме употребляются еще слова:

не горазд
не люб
не надобен.

И те и другие пишутся с "не" раздельно.
Но, с другой стороны, Рахманова пишет: "В.В. Виноградов включал в категорию состояния: 
1) краткие прилагательные, утратившие свои полные формы: рад, должен;".

Так что же прилагательное "должен" все-таки не имеет полной формы или имеет, но ее значение другое?